# jQuery filter.me .ACV file conversion

Tags: jquery, photoshop, curves

I am using the jQuery filter.me script to apply some filters to my images. The script comes with 6 preset filters, but it says you can convert any Photoshop `.acv curves file` and apply that as a filter. When I look at the development script, it reads a `.acv file` directly. However, in the production script, the curves files are represented by the following `A,R,G,B` values. My question is, how can I convert one of my custom .acv curves files that I create in Photoshop, into these `A,R,G,B` values so I can use them in this script? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
'a':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,255], `
'r':[32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,34,35,36,38,39,41,43,45,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,96,98,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,114,116,117,119,121,123,125,126,128,130,132,133,135,137,139,140,142,144,146,147,149,151,152,154,155,157,158,160,161,163,164,166,167,168,170,171,172,173,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,197,198,199,200,201,201,202,203,204,204,205,205,206,206,207,207,208,208,209,209,210,210,211,211,212,212,213,213,214,214,215,215,216,216,217,217,218,218,219,219,220,220,221,221,221,222,222,223,223,224,224,225,225,225,226,226,227,227,228,228,228,229,229,230,230,231,231,231,232,232,233,233,233,234,234,235,235,235,236,236,236,237,237,238,238,238,239,239,239,240,240,240,241,241,242,242,242,243,243,243,244,244,245,245,245,246,246,247,248,248,249,249,250,250,251,251,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252],` 
'g':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,23,24,25,27,28,30,31,33,34,36,37,39,40,42,44,45,47,49,50,52,54,56,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,78,80,82,85,87,89,92,94,97,99,102,104,106,109,111,114,116,118,121,123,125,127,129,131,133,135,137,139,141,143,145,146,148,150,152,154,156,157,159,161,163,164,166,168,169,171,173,174,176,178,179,181,182,184,185,187,188,190,191,192,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,205,206,207,207,208,209,209,210,210,211,211,211,212,212,213,213,213,214,214,215,215,216,216,216,217,217,218,218,219,219,220,220,220,221,221,222,222,222,223,223,224,224,225,225,225,226,226,227,227,228,228,228,229,229,230,230,231,231,232,232,232,233,233,234,234,235,235,236,236,237,237,238,238,239,239,239,240,240,241,241,242,242,243,244,244,245,246,246,247,248,249,249,250,250,251,251,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252,252], `
'b':[2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,11,12,12,13,13,14,15,15,16,17,17,18,19,19,20,21,22,23,24,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,36,38,39,40,42,43,45,47,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,87,89,91,93,95,96,98,100,101,103,105,107,108,110,112,113,115,117,118,120,122,123,125,127,128,130,131,133,135,136,138,140,141,143,145,146,148,149,151,153,154,156,158,159,161,163,164,166,167,169,170,171,173,174,175,177,178,179,180,182,183,184,185,186,187,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,195,196,197,198,198,199,200,200,201,201,202,202,203,203,204,204,204,205,205,205,206,206,206,207,207,207,207,208,208,209,209,209,210,210,211,211,211,212,212,213,213,214,214,214,215,215,216,216,216,217,217,218,218,218,219,219,220,220,220,221,221,222,222,222,223,223,224,224,225,225,226,226,227,227,227,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228,228]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could read the [Photoshop File Formats Specifications (PDF)](http://pypsd.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/Photoshop_File_Formats.pdf). See page 72.

[image]

You want to see **page 72**. Ask about anything. You might want to open the ACV file in a hex editor first just to double check the expected values of curves before writing your code to extract those amounts.